# Root UIView in UIViewController cannot be resized

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have two separate projects with elements laid out in a .storyboard file: one has a ViewController whose root View can be resized, the other one has a ViewController and View with (as far as I can see) the same parameters, but the root View cannot be resized. What am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer, but some advice for figuring out the answer: Storyboard files are XML.  Make copies of the two storyboards, delete everything but the objects in question, and diff the files.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that if there is a transition going TO the ViewController containing the View, it can be resized, otherwise not. But it doesn't make much sense for it to be resizable, since when the app is run, the full extent of the View is seen anyway. Decoupled Views can of course be resized. So I guess any time a root View can be resized, it's basically a bug in XCode.